# React Redux Array state change in Function Component not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

useEffect is not working even through the array state changed.

I am first adding the amount in to transactions array through `dispatch(addTransaction(10))`.

Then I want to count the array sum by dispatching `dispatch(countTotal(transactions))`.

I am not sure where its going wrong.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { addTransaction } from './actions/transActions';
import { countTotal } from './actions/countActions';

import { shallowEqual, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


function App() {
  const transactions = useSelector(state => {
   return state.trans.transactions


});

  const count = useSelector(state => state.count.total);
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", transactions)
    dispatch(countTotal(transactions))
  }, [transactions])

  console.log('transactions', transactions)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
       <h1>{count}</h1>
       <br></br>
       <div>
       <button style={{width:90, height:60, fontSize: 40, backgroundColor: 'teal', border: '0px', color: 'white'}} onClick={() => {
        dispatch(addTransaction(10))
        }} type="button"> + 10</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button style={{width:90, height:60, fontSize: 40, backgroundColor: 'indianred', border: '0px', color: 'white'}}  onClick={() => dispatch(addTransaction(-10))} type="button"> - 10 </button>

       </div>
       </header>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

addTransaction code:

```
export const addTransaction = (amount) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TRANSACTION",
        payload: amount,
      })
}
```

Reducer code :

```
const initialState = {
    transactions : []
  };
  
  export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
        console.log('ADD_TRANS', action.payload)
        let trans = state.transactions;
        trans.push(action.payload)

        return {
          ...state,
          transactions: trans
        };
      default:
       return state;
    }
  }
```

Everything is working fine. Even `dispatch(countTotal(transactions))` also working. Except when I am triggering it in useEffect its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Because you provided `transactions` in the dependency array of `useEffect`. When you provide some state in `useEffect` dependency array, it means the `useEffect` will only trigger when that state changes. If you need to call `countTotal` everytime the component renders and `transactions` changes, you can use two `useEffect`.

Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: I need to trigger the useEffect when ever the transactions array got updated. So, transactions array is getting updated but useEffect code not executing.

Answer (score 1):

Issue got fixed by changing reducer part o the code as array getting updated but state change is detecting.

```
const initialState = {
    transactions : []
  };
  
  export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
        console.log('ADD_TRANS', action.payload)
        let trans = [...state.transactions, action.payload]

        return {
          ...state,
          transactions: trans
        };
      default:
       return state;
    }
  }
```

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `push` in a reducer in "bare Redux", because it is mutating the state, but the state should be considered immutable. Also you should not use bare Redux, instead you should use Redux Toolkit, which uses a library under the hood that makes it possible to use `push` and any other mutating code without any risk for similar bugs.

Comment: Adding to that: Redux Toolkit is the official recommendation for any newly written Redux code since 2019. Please go and read https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code too much and want to continue with this code then there is a quick fix for this issue.
You should take and extra state in the reducer and toggle it and start listening to it Like below

Reducer Code:

```
const initialState = {
    transactions : [],
    refresh: false
  };
  
  export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_TRANSACTION":
        console.log('ADD_TRANS', action.payload)
        let trans = state.transactions;
        trans.push(action.payload)

        return {
          ...state,
          transactions: trans
          refresh: !state.refresh
        };
      default:
       return state;
    }
  }
```

Main file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { addTransaction } from './actions/transActions';
import { countTotal } from './actions/countActions';

import { shallowEqual, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


function App() {
  const transactions = useSelector(state => {
   return state.trans.transactions
});
  const refresh = useSelector(state => state.trans.refresh);

  const count = useSelector(state => state.count.total);
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", transactions)
    dispatch(countTotal(transactions))
  }, [transactions, refresh])

  console.log('transactions', transactions)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
       <h1>{count}</h1>
       <br></br>
       <div>
       <button style={{width:90, height:60, fontSize: 40, backgroundColor: 'teal', border: '0px', color: 'white'}} onClick={() => {
        dispatch(addTransaction(10))
        }} type="button"> + 10</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button style={{width:90, height:60, fontSize: 40, backgroundColor: 'indianred', border: '0px', color: 'white'}}  onClick={() => dispatch(addTransaction(-10))} type="button"> - 10 </button>

       </div>
       </header>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```